# Program skipping every second value for given integer

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to create a program that when giving it an integer, it will display every second value going from 1 to the integer (i) and also from i to 1. I have it working for i to 1 but cannot seem to get it working for the forward direction

```
def skip (i): 
    for i in range(n, 0, -1):
        print(i, end = " ")
    return skip(n-2)
```

Comment: `range(1,n+1)` will go the other way ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley Yeah, I was wrong.  Deleted the comment.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're asking for:

```
 def skip(n):

     print("1 to n in steps of 2")
     for i in range(1, n+1, 2):
         print(i)

     print("n to 1 in steps of -2")
     for i in range(n, 0, -2):
         print(i)
```

Which produces this output for inputs of 10 and 11

```
>>> skip(10)
1 to n in steps of 2
1
3
5
7
9
n to 1 in steps of -2
10
8
6
4
2

>>> skip(11)
1 to n in steps of 2
1
3
5
7
9
11
n to 1 in steps of -2
11
9
7
5
3
1
```